# Easier way to print out each iterable in a map function?

Tags: python

I'm super new to Python with a bad teacher and we're currently trying to make a simple program that will print out a states' capital when you enter the states' name. We're using maps to do this and I can't figure out how to print the capital after you enter the states name.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
states = {
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
    'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
    'California': 'Sacramento',
}

state = input('What state would you like to see the capital of?')
```

I've thought about going through one by one for each state with something that would look like this, but I really need a more efficient way rather than typing 300 lines of code to get the job done:

```
if state == states['California']:
    print(states['California'])
```

And so on, one by one for each state. I'd really appreciate any ideas you all have, I haven't been able to come up with anything else from other online resources I've gone through. Thanks :)!

Comment: `print(states[state])` (though I would be inclined to name the dictionary based on the values rather than the keys, i.e. `capitals` rather than `states` - then you would do `print(capitals[state])` which is more intuitive

Comment: Wait, you're not using a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), you're using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), which is a [mapp*ing*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping). Also, check out the official tutorial on [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: @wjandrea Okay, thanks! And sorry, my current Python teacher said it was a map. He told us he doesn't actually know Python, just R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
states = {
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
    'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
    'California': 'Sacramento',
}

state = input('What state would you like to see the capital of?   ')

print(states.get(state, "Sorry, not found!"))
```

Python's [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) takes two arguments. The first argument is the key for which the value is to be returned. Second argument (this one is optional) is the value that is to be returned if the specified key isn't in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user value exists in the map itself:

```py
if state in states:
  print(states[state])
```